# Sharedpreference dont seem to work , unable to display stored data

Tags: java, android, android-studio, sharedpreferences

here is my code

**Setting values in Preference:**

```
@Override
    public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {

        final ViewHolder holder;

        if(convertView == null){
            holder = new ViewHolder();
            convertView=inflater.inflate(resource, null);
            holder.tvItemName = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.tvItemName);
            holder.tvPrice = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.tvPrice);
            holder.bLess = (Button) convertView.findViewById(R.id.bLess);
            holder.bAdd = (Button) convertView.findViewById(R.id.bAdd);
            holder.etItemQuantity = (EditText) convertView.findViewById(R.id.etItemQuantity);
            holder.bAddToCart = (Button) convertView.findViewById(R.id.bAddToCart);
            convertView.setTag(holder);
        }else {
            holder = (ViewHolder) convertView.getTag();
        }

        holder.tvItemName.setText(itemModelList.get(position).getItemName());
        holder.tvPrice.setText("Rs " + itemModelList.get(position).getSalesRate());

        holder.bAdd.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                int qty = Integer.parseInt(holder.etItemQuantity.getText().toString().trim());
                qty++;
                holder.etItemQuantity.setText(""+qty);
            }
        });

        holder.bLess.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                int qty = Integer.parseInt(holder.etItemQuantity.getText().toString().trim());
                if(qty != 0){
                    qty--;
                    holder.etItemQuantity.setText(""+qty);
                }
            }
        });
        final String itemName = itemModelList.get(position).getItemName();
        final String salesRate = itemModelList.get(position).getSalesRate();


        holder.bAddToCart.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                SharedPreferences prefs = getSharedPreferences("my_prefs", MODE_PRIVATE);
                SharedPreferences.Editor edit = prefs.edit();
                edit.putString("itemName", itemName );
                edit.putString("salesRate", salesRate );
                edit.commit();
                Toast.makeText(Items.this,"Added item to cart", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            }
        });
        return convertView;
    }
```

**Retrieve data from preference:**

```
public class CartDisplay extends AppCompatActivity {
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.row_cart_display);

    TextView tvItemName = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.tvItemName);
    TextView tvSalesRate = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.tvSalesRate);
    TextView tvTotalAmount = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.tvTotalAmount);


    SharedPreferences prefs = getSharedPreferences("my_prefs", MODE_PRIVATE);
    String restoredText = prefs.getString("text", null);
    if (restoredText != null) {
        String itemName = prefs.getString("itemName", "No itemName defined");//"No name defined" is the default value.
        String salesRate = prefs.getString("salesRate", "0");//"0" is the default value.
        tvItemName.setText(itemName);
        tvSalesRate.setText("RS "+salesRate);
        tvTotalAmount.setText("Total: RS" +salesRate);
    }

}
```

[image: Here is how the view looks]

idk why my code dont work

- iam trying to send itemname and salesrate to next activity but it
  wont display that in here it works if i use bundle or intents
- also i want to store etItemQuantity value in sharedprefrences btw idk
  how make qty variable global so that i can store the value on
  addToCart button click

really need help here guys, [here is my full code](https://github.com/sooorajjj/KOT)

Comment: where did you set value for "text"

Comment: ah , i was referring to [this](http://stackoverflow.com/a/23024962/4131811) example of using sharedPreferences

Comment: check updated answer

Comment: check updated answer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### EDIT 2

Create `Application` class store qty variable there and access anywhere in app.

#### See [example](http://androidexample.com/Global_Variable_Or_Application_Context_Variable_-_Android_Example/index.php?view=article_discription&aid=114&aaid=136) for creating application class

---

### EDIT 1

As you were referring  example `if (restoredText != null) {` might be used to check whether `SharedPreference` has value or not. user is trying to avoid checking **null** for every value. So he set one value for "text"

You are not setting text value just paste below code remove if statement .

```
 String name = prefs.getString("name", "No name defined");//"No name defined" is the default value.
 int idName = prefs.getInt("idName", 0);
```

---

I think

```
 String restoredText = prefs.getString("text", null);
```

returning **null** so `if` statement is not executing

```
if (restoredText != null) { ...}
```

Comment: eh ? why will it return null i have putStrings in there

Comment: where dud you set value for  "text" in shared preference , you are only getting value for key "text" & default value is "null"

Comment: Oh ohk iam sorry my mistake i have [fixed that](https://github.com/sooorajjj/KOT/commit/b5495a76c14a1d639e3f0f62bcfa2510b06544b5)

can you please answer the 2nd part of my question

Comment: if i can set Global Variable like that then i guess i dont need sharedpreferences ?

Comment: Yes you don't need

Answer (score 1):

I have found some logic mistake in your code . Here it was

```
String restoredText = prefs.getString("text", null);
// you are trying to fetch the value of "text" but you had forgot to put /save the "text" value in your code 


SharedPreferences prefs = getSharedPreferences("my_prefs", MODE_PRIVATE);
            SharedPreferences.Editor edit = prefs.edit();
            edit.putString("itemName", itemName );
            edit.putString("salesRate", salesRate );
            edit.commit();
```

Solution: put some value in "text" , during save and try to fetch again. 
Like this

```
SharedPreferences prefs = getSharedPreferences("my_prefs", MODE_PRIVATE);
            SharedPreferences.Editor edit = prefs.edit();
            edit.putString("text", "text" );
            edit.putString("itemName", itemName );
            edit.putString("salesRate", salesRate );
            edit.commit();

String restoredText = prefs.getString("text", null);
if (restoredText.equals("text")) {
    String itemName = prefs.getString("itemName", "No itemName defined");//"No name defined" is the default value.
    String salesRate = prefs.getString("salesRate", "0");//"0" is the default value.
    tvItemName.setText(itemName);
    tvSalesRate.setText("RS "+salesRate);
    tvTotalAmount.setText("Total: RS" +salesRate);
}
```

Comment: Hey thanks that fixed it can you answer the 2nd part of my question ?

Comment: save the qunty value in share pref as like as itemName we stored and fetch using same process .

Comment: cant assign qty as a final variable

Comment: int value=Integer.parseInt(holder.etItemQuantity.getText().toString()); and then save in share pref.

Comment: Thanks that worked , i have a few more questions on my current project you down to help ? we can possibly move this discussion to some  better chat client  , hangouts / gtalk / messenger , my mail sooorajjj@gmail.com or you can drop by your mail so i could reach out 
, thanks

Answer (score 0):

I think the problem is this line

```
 String restoredText = prefs.getString("text", null);
if (restoredText != null) { ... }
```

I don't see where you put this value in sharepreference and you check != null here so code in that block never be called.

Comment: Oh ohk iam sorry my mistake i have [fixed that](https://github.com/sooorajjj/KOT/commit/b5495a76c14a1d639e3f0f62bcfa2510b06544b5)

can you please answer the 2nd part of my question

Answer (score 0):

Use following methods to get and set sharedPreferences:

```
static public boolean setPreference(Context c, String value, String key) {
    SharedPreferences settings = c.getSharedPreferences(PREFS_NAME, 0);
    settings = c.getSharedPreferences(PREFS_NAME, 0);
    SharedPreferences.Editor editor = settings.edit();
    editor.putString(key, value);
    return editor.commit();
}

static public String getPreference(Context c, String key) {
    SharedPreferences settings = c.getSharedPreferences(PREFS_NAME, 0);
    settings = c.getSharedPreferences(PREFS_NAME, 0);
    String value = settings.getString(key, "");
    return value;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you need to use application context while storing values in SharedPreference like this.

```
SharedPreferences pref = getApplicationContext().getSharedPreferences("MyPref", MODE_PRIVATE); 
    Editor editor = pref.edit();
```